# IEEEeqnarray with multiple alignment points

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, columns

I've got a long persistent question on how to typeset a particular equation using `IEEEeqnarray`.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCllr}
\IEEEyesnumber  \IEEEyessubnumber*
\min_{ y_i} &\quad& \sum_{i=1}^M \big(\frac 12 y_i^\top Q_i y_i \,+\, &q_i^\top  y_i + K_i\big) \, & \text{(agent objective)}\\
\text{s.t.} && C_i y_i=c_i& \forall i  &\text{(agent dynamic)}\\
&& {y}_i^{lb} \leq  y_i \leq {y}_i^{ub} & \forall i &\text{(agent bound)}\\
&& D  y  = d  & &\text{(coupling of agents)}.
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

resulting in the output

[image]

where I've added vertical red lines to indicate the horizontal alignment. *(Please ignore the weird looking 0.xx tags.)*

**What I want to achieve:**

[image]

i.e. I want the last right-oriented column to be moved closer to the rest of the equation, in particular I don't want the position of `coupling of agents` in the last row be determined by `K_i)` in the first row. Please note that I also want to keep the actual (numbered) tags beside the written-out ones.

**Why do I want this:**
The equation is used for a two-column paper where horizontal space is scarce.

**Own ideas about a possible solution:**

- The desired behavior is very similar to using `\hfill` in a text environment. This however does not work here (placing `\hfill` into the equation has no effect).
- The key point would be having orientation points (marked by `&`) in line 2-4 that are independent of line 1. This would also simplify the placement of `\forall i` and would still allow to have a common flushright orientation. No idea though how to achieve this.
- Another possibility would be placing the written out descriptions into the actual tags, but then I would only have either one of them, while I need both here. Please don't argue that I shouldn't have two types of tags, this is motivated by context not given here.

Thanks for all answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of `\rlap` directives will let you achieve your formatting objective. The `\rlap` directive in the first row serves to snug up the material in the final column, by the width of `${}_i\bigr)$`. The second directive, in the final row, is optional and merely serves to align the closing parentheses properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCllr}
\IEEEyesnumber  \IEEEyessubnumber*
\min_{y_i} &\quad& \sum_{i=1}^M \bigl(\tfrac{1}{2} y_i^\top Q_i y_i +{} 
      &q_i^\top  y^{}_i + K\rlap{${}_i\bigr)$}  & \text{(agent objective)}\\
\text{s.t.} 
    && C_i y_i=c_i& \forall i  &\text{(agent dynamic)}\\
    && {y}_i^{lb} \leq  y^{}_i \leq {y}_i^{ub} & \forall i &\text{(agent bound)}\\
    && D  y  = d  & &\text{(coupling of agents)}\rlap{.}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Felix - Glad I was able to help. :-) Incidentally, do note that I also replaced `\,+\, &` in your code with the somewhat more robust `+{}&`.